# Why can't I get on NFL.com on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, firefox, internet, google-chrome

Every time I try to get on NFL.com using Windows 7 and a variety of browsers, it times out.

I've tried these browsers:

- `Safari (even changing the user agent does nothing)`
- `Google Chrome`
- `IE 8 (and IE 8 with compatibility mode turned on)`
- `Firefox`

So then I tried to ping the website, they all timed out. **But when I use Linux (Ubuntu 9.04) on the same computer I can access the website just fine.**

So why can't I open this website on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's the OS per se.  I just browsed to NFL.com on Windows 7 with Chrome, loaded just fine.  Are you behind some sort of proxy that might be blocking certain sites? (Like at work).

Edit per comment:  Have you checked your host file?  Do you have peerguardian running?

Comment: No it's my personal computer with no proxy.

Comment: Which build of Windows 7 do you have?

Comment: I have Build 7100.

Comment: Thats the same build I have. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Was this the answer? it looks like you're still stuck...